# Usage of ese/esa/eso with implied gender

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, género

A friend from Argentina (native) and I (non-native) have been arguing for the past few hours about the grammatical validity of the following bolded sentence:

> «Este hecho es interesante: Todo el territorio canadiense de Nunavut cabe dentro de México.»
>
> «**Ya sabía ese.**»

He believes that the sentence is grammatically correct because there is an implied gender in the "ese" (*el hecho*), which he backs up with sources [[1]](https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/288991/what-is-the-difference-between-esteesta-eseea-and-eso)[[2]](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/spanish-easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-spanish-demonstrative-pronouns-este-ese-and-aquel)[[3]](https://preply.com/en/learn/spanish/grammar/pronouns/demonstrative-pronouns). These sources state something along the lines of the following:

> The neuter forms (esto, eso, aquello) are used to talk about **an object you don’t recognize** or **about an idea or statement**.

His argument is that, since I'm not referring to an idea or a statement, but rather a fact (*el hecho*), *ese* (instead of *eso*) is the correct word to use. Is he correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Some may say](https://www.palmbeachstate.edu/slc/Documents/fact%20or%20opinion%20hints.pdf) that "a fact is a **statement** that can be verified. It can be proven to be true or false through objective evidence". So you're referring to a statement there, this one: "Todo el territorio canadiense de Nunavut cabe dentro de México". So it matches the rule that you found.

You can find a similar example having a fact replaced by "eso" [here](https://www.rae.es/gram%C3%A1tica/sintaxis/los-demostrativos-neutros) in a more reputed source, the RAE, as part of a detailed explanation about the use of "demostrativos neutros" in Spanish.

> En Mogador **los grillos buscan el calor del fuego** y por **eso** se alojan en las cocinas de las casas

The fact/statement: los grillos buscan el calor del fuego
Replaced by: eso

In Spain, we would use "eso" in your example but the other variant is not grammatically incorrect as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate issues:

- is it right or wrong?
- what is most appropriate? natural?

Is *ese* right? Yes, it refers to *the words* "este hecho".

Is *eso* right? Yes, it refers to *a fact* about certain Canadian territory.

What is most appropriate? I don't know... What is most natural? I think, in this case, *eso* is what most native speakers would say, in general.

But check this out:

> -- Este chiste es divertido: Qué hace una rata en una esquina? [...]
>
> -- Ya sabía ese.

Here the structure is vey similar, but *ese* is the usual (refers to *este chiste*). Because a joke is not a fact/statement, we do not use *eso* here.

Comment: Ahora quiero saber: ¿qué hace una rata en una esquina?

Comment: Good point. The pronoun "ese" works well for "chiste" in that position after the verb "saber", but not for "hecho".

Comment: @A.R. Está esperando un rato. 

Answer (score 2):

Basic summary:

- that -> eso
- that one -> ese/esa

"Ya sabía eso" = "I already knew that"

"Ya sabía esa (pregunta)" = "I already knew that one" (while playing Trivial Pursuit, or working with flashcards, for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you translate that conversation into English, you would have:

```
-Here is a fun fact. All the territory of Nunavut fits inside Mexico.
-I already knew that.
```

But, if you are talking about fun facts and your friend comes up with one, you might answer slightly differently:

```
-Here is a fun fact. All the territory of Nunavut fits inside Mexico.
-I already knew that one. [Meaning: I already knew that fun fact.]
```

We have the same difference in Spanish. If there is a known antecedent (in this case, *hecho interesante*), you may use *ese* as a gendered pronoun that substitutes for the known antecedent; otherwise, you should use *eso*, which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of translation into Spanish:

*ese/esa* is that [noun] (masculine or feminine word). *eso* just means that. Personally, on the Internet, if I want to say I already know **that** I would say: *Ya sabía eso*. And not: Ya sabía ese. I already knew that one [ese hecho].

«Este hecho es interesante: Todo el territorio canadiense de Nunavut cabe dentro de México.»

«Ya sabía ese.» [I already knew that fact.]

Yes, ese is masculine and would be for el hecho.
**But this is not a grammar question. It is about what one says in situ**.

«Este hecho es interesante: Todo el territorio canadiense de Nunavut cabe dentro de México.»

«Ya sabía eso.»

I already knew that. Where that refers to the whole sentence and not to any individual word in it.

So, you are both right. He is right about the grammar but I believe you are right about the situation.

Comment: Pues, en este caso, a mí no me importa la distincción entre los dos. Tienes razón, _eso_ se refiere a la declaración "Todo el territorio..." y _ese_ refiere al "hecho," pero aquí el hecho y la declaración son lo mismo. Así es una distincción _de gramática_ solamente, pero no una distincción _semántica_. El significado es igual. Quizás lo mejor es ésto: ese y esa se traduce como _that one_, y eso como _that_ solamente.

Comment: Al contrario, para mí, la diferencia está en la situación pragmática. La deíxis no es lo mismo. Decir *eso* y *ese* que implica [el hecho] no es exactamente igual.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, la deíxis difiere un poco. Aún así, ninguna manera es errónea. Necessitaría más contexto para decedir cual preferiría. Ordinariamente, preferiría _eso_. Pero imagine: dos amigos se turnan para contar hechos los que no sabe el otro. Ahora, preferiría _ese_.